# How to import and scale imported image?

Tags: c++, qt

I have that code and I want to import images from computer and scale it to 600x600. Can you help me how to do it?

```
QStringList nameFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this,tr("Open file"),"C:\\",tr("JPG/PNG files (*.jpg; *.png);;All files (*.*)") );
if(!nameFile.isEmpty())
{
    for (int i=0;i<nameFile.count();i++)
    {
        string path = nameFile.at(i).toStdString();;
        ui->listImages->addItem(nameFile.at(i));
        temp = new QImage(600,600,QImage::Format_RGB32);
        temp -> load(QString().fromStdString(path));
        pic.push_back(temp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code. 
This is working for me.

```
//CREATE AN IMAGE OBJECT
QImage *img = new QImage(); 

//LOAD THE SOURCE IMAGE
bool value = img->load(QString("C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\Desktop\\test.png"));

//SCALE THE IMAGE
QImage newImage  = img->scaled(600, 600);

//USE IT
newImage.save("C:\\Users\\XXXXXX\\Desktop\\test1234.png");
```

As I do not know the types in your code for some variables,
By roughly your code may look as shown below (Very rough.... a lot you have to take care)

```
QStringList nameFile = QFileDialog::getOpenFileNames(this,tr("Open file"),"C:\\",tr("JPG/PNG files (*.jpg; *.png);;All files (*.*)") );
if(!nameFile.isEmpty())
{
    for (int i=0;i<nameFile.count();i++)
    {
        QString path = nameFile.at(i);
        ui->listImages->addItem(nameFile.at(i));


        //Do IT HERE
        QImage img;
        bool value = img.load(path );
        QImage newImage  = img.scaled(600, 600);


        pic.push_back(newImage);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Take a look at `QImage:transformed` for full control, else `QImage::scaledToWidth` for an easier ride.